# UTF-8 meta charset, not working

Tags: php, html, utf-8, meta, utf

Im having some trouble formatting my HTML code to UTF-8. I have HTML and PHP on the same page. I used notepad++ but alredy formated in general settings to save file in UTF-8 withot BOM. But still i get characters like "?".

Ive checked my headers and seems that it is UTF-8:
[image: UTF8]

This is between my header tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Hope some of you could help me with this. If there is need for the HTML file just shout out.

I have been using Notepad++ as editor and some parts i have edited online on hosting editor(one.com) but that shouldt be a problem as the file is saved as UTF-8 and told to browser with meta tag that it should also read as UTF-8.

Thanks for the help :) - Asim

Comment: What type of data is showing up with `?`? Is it pure HTML, content inside the HTML, etc? Are you loading anything from external files, like database, or pure text-files, or other sources?

Comment: And where do you get these characters that produce `?`

Comment: Does the font you're using support those characters?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Yes, i am loading data from external file(Database) but using PHP on same page as HTML.

Comment: Is the file or database set to be UTF-8 ??

Comment: Go through your database and make it `utf8_general_ci`. It should solve your problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly both are set to be UTF-8. i just tried "mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8") " but that did not fix it. both my db and html is UTF-8

Comment: mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');  fixed my problem